# How to do Decimal to float conversion in Python?

Tags: python, type-conversion

I need to convert a `Decimal` value to `float` in Python. Is there any method available for this type conversion?

Comment: 32 / 64 / 128  bit float ?

Answer (score 83):

There are two methods:

- `float_number = float(decimal_number)`
- `float_number = decimal_number * 1.0`

First one using the built in function and second one without any function, but take care about the `1.0` not `1` as it should be float so the result will be float.

Comment: Btw `float_number = decimal_number * 1.0` does not work in python 2 -> unsuported operand types

Comment: implicit cast (Decimal * 1.0) doesn't work in python 3.5 or 3.6 either

Answer (score 49):

Just use `float`:

```
float_number = float(decimal_number)
```

Answer (score 8):

Just cast it to float:

```
 number_in_float = float(number_you_have)
```