# Serialize JSON from Python dataclass that has Decimal

Tags: python, json, serialization, decimal, python-dataclasses

I have a class in Python called `TransactionData`:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from decimal import *


@dataclass(unsafe_hash=True)
class TransactionData:
    date: str
    transaction: str
    cheque_no: str
    debit: Decimal
    credit: Decimal
    balance: Decimal

    def __post_init__(self):
        if not isinstance(self.date, str):
            raise ValueError('date provided is not a string.')
        if not isinstance(self.transaction, str):
            raise ValueError('transaction provided is not a string.')
        if not isinstance(self.cheque_no, str):
            raise ValueError('cheque_no provided is not a string.')
        if not isinstance(self.debit, Decimal):
            raise ValueError('debit provided is not a Decimal.')
        if not isinstance(self.credit, Decimal):
            raise ValueError('credit provided is not a Decimal.')
        if not isinstance(self.balance, Decimal):
            raise ValueError('balance provided is not a Decimal.')
```

I want to serialize it to a Json with `json.dumps()`. I have extended `JSONEncoder` to be able to serialize `Decimal`:

```
import decimal
class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
            return str(o)
        return super(DecimalEncoder, self).default(o)
```

Now I try to serialize `TransactionData`:

```
transaction = TransactionData(
    '28 Aug','Cheque', '187264', Decimal('100.00'), Decimal('200.00'), Decimal('300.00'))

json.dumps(transaction, cls=DecimalEncoder)
```

I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: Object of type TransactionData is not JSON serializable

I've heard you can use `simplejson` for this but I would still prefer to use the standard json library going forward. What is the solution to this?

Comment: This looks very helpful @mkrieger1, but how do I serialize the `Decimal` in the dataclass then? I'm confused now...

Comment: Just as you did before, by converting it to `str`: `if isinstance(o, TransactionData): return {k: str(v) for k, v in dataclasses.asdict(o).items()}`, for example.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Oh thanks!!! One last thing though please... If I wanted the last three fields `debit`, `credit` and `balance` to come out as a number, what's the syntax? Currently they are all printing as strings.

Comment: Maybe convert them to a number instead of a string? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32285927/how-to-do-decimal-to-float-conversion-in-python However if you use Decimal instead of float you *do* want strings to keep the precision.

Comment: I personally would use a (de)serialization tool like the [dataclass-wizard](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/), and then you don't need to define a __post_init__() method. Also you can just do something like `TransactionData.from_dict({'debit': '1.2', ...})` and it should load the correct or desired types.